Can RegisterClipboardFormat in WinAPI change returned integer after some time?
As the title says - I'm wondering if RegisterClipboardFormat in WinAPI changes returned integer value after some time. I've registered my clipboard format, but after some time I've noticed it changes the underlying integer value, although it can be the same (for some time) after different runs of the application. I know this seems like an answer to my question, but I just want to make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong.
I haven't found information about this in the documentation, and part of current application's logic uses integer values directly, so that's probably dangerous if it's behaving in a way that I've specified in the question.

The documentation says: "If the function succeeds, the return value identifies the registered clipboard format.". I don't see any guarantee about the value being fixed.

"I've noticed it changes the underlying integer value" - What is "it"? And how do you even verify this? The documentation on RegisterClipboardFormat is pretty clear. "If the function succeeds, the return value identifies the registered clipboard format." IDs don't just change.

@IInspectable sorry, what I've meant - I see in the debugger between runs, that the value of the integer persists. But after some time, like after nth run, it changes.

Not I dupe, as I think it's not conclusive Does Windows recycle/reuse Registered Clipboard Format ids ie experimental results but no documentation link

There is no guarantee that a clipboard format that was unregistered receives the same numeric ID value the next time the format is registered. That's an odd expectation. The name you use to register the format is the persistent identifier. The numeric ID is just an implementation artifact you can use in your (suite of) programs.

There is no guarantee, it may persist in the same logon session or boot or whatever. But you don't need to assume anything. Just call RegisterClipboardFormat with your fixed string and use whatever integer you get back.

@IInspectable:  You cannot unregister a clipboard format.

@MichaelChourdakis:  The guarantee: "If a registered format with the specified name already exists, a new format is not registered and the return value identifies the existing format." "RegisterClipboardFormat [adds] entries to the user atom table." "[E]ntries added by ... RegisterClipboardFormat do not get deleted until the session ends."  The identifier is an ATOM.  In fact, the documentation says you can find the name of any user ATOM by calling Get_ClipboardFormat_Name, even if the ATOM wasn't one returned by registering a clipboard format.

@AdrianMcCarthy I didn't suggest that you could. Meanwhile, I also didn't suggest that the system couldn't/wouldn't. There seems to be evidence that the system does recycle clipboard format atoms.

When you said "after some time", that include a logoff/logon? Clipboard format registrations do not survive logoff.

The RegisterClipboardFormat documentation mentions the following about the return value:

If the function succeeds, the return value identifies the registered
clipboard format. If the function fails, the return value is zero.

It does not guarantee that different calls with the same format name will return the same value.
In practice this should not matter to you.
You should do 2 only things with this UINT value (none of them require it to be fixed between calls):

Check that it is not 0 to verify the function succeeded.
Keep the UINT value that the API returned if you need to use it with other functions.
Two examples of such functions are IsClipboardFormatAvailable and SetClipboardData.
Using them is related to a specific clipboard registration, identified by the value returned from the last call of RegisterClipboardFormat for this format.

You can see an extensive example of using clipboard functions here: Using the Clipboard.

The point of registering a clipboard format is to have a way for at least two processes to identify the same thing by name.  Both processes call RegisterClipboardFormat.  The first one will get a unique value, and the second one must get the same value.  In fact, every subsequent call with the same string (for the duration of the registration) must return the same value to ensure processes can exchange data through the clipboard.

@AdrianMcCarthy this is not exactly what the OP observed (see their comment).

@AdrianMcCarthy why do you say the 2 processed must get the same value ? It seems like as long as they use the same format name (string) each process can use the the ID they get to access the same clipboard. Am I wrong ?

@AdrianMcCarthy to continue my previous comment. The documentation says that "If a registered format with the specified name already exists, a new format is not registered and the return value identifies the existing format.". It doesn't say that the return value cannot change. My understanding is that it can, as long as the value corresponds to the same format.

Because the ID returned by RegisterClipboardFormatW is an atom, and that's how atoms work. It's different than how handles work. Two processes with access to the same shared object will have different handle. But two processes (in the same session) referencing the same string stored in an atom table will have the same atom. In fact, process A could register a clipboard format and pass its atom to process B, and process B would be able to access that clipboard format without making its own call RegisterClipboardFormatW. (I wouldn't recommend that design, but it does work.)

@AdrianMcCarthy it might well be, you seem to be proficient
with Windows internals. But as far as I saw it is not specified in the documentation for RegisterClipboardFormat (the term atom is actually not even mentioned there). So the question is: is it guaranteed to be that way ? Reading the documentation as is, I believe the system is usable without that guarantee.

It's the atom table documentation that tells us clipboard format IDs are atoms:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-atom-tables#user-atom-table

The IDs returned by RegisterClipboardFormatW are ATOMs.  (Registered window classes and messages are also ATOMs.)
The OS maintains a global atom table for the system, and another called the user atom table.
(An application can also create its own local atom table, which lasts for the duration of the execution, but that table isn't relevant here.)
Clipboard formats (unlike window classes) cannot be unregistered. Clipboard formats are registered in the user atom table and thus should be stable for the life of the user's session, which ends when they log out, or the machine restarts (e.g., after a crash, power failure, or updates).
My guess is that the different values observed for the same clipboard format happened in different sessions.

Is it specified anywhere what exactly do OS mean by "session"? It certainly doesn't seem to be a program execution, as I executed it 4-5 times and the value persisted. Something else has to hold the "session", right?

The observed behavior is in disagreement with the documentation.

@tetektoza:  No, the vagueness about "the session" is part of why I said the documentation isn't crystal clear.   I think it's safe to say it's at least the duration of the user's login session, but more likely they're referring to the time between restarts of the OS.

@IInspectable:  Not necessarily.  The OP may have observed different values in different sessions.

There's no indication in that comment that the OP restarted the system. This part in the documentation ("However, the entries added by RegisterWindowMessage and RegisterClipboardFormat do not get deleted until the session ends.") thus doesn't appear to be true (any more). Given how much pressure the Shell alone puts on the user atom table (via registered messages) the system may have seen an update to more aggressively recycle atoms.

"Session" is a Windows term. All the services share one Session ("session zero"), and another Session for each user who is logged in (or trying to log in). Details. For the purpose of this question, it's basically "until the user logs off". Note that if two users are logged on, each has a different session.
